# How to handle image backgrounds for retina display

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am designing a game that makes use of large backgrounds. These are illustrated backgrounds, that are currently sitting at around 4.5 MB and as backgrounds, are sitting in the scene for the entirety of the game.

First, I am not sure if this would cause memory usage to amp up, but I imagine it would, given that there are also other overlaid textures on the screen. That is my first question: can it cause memory issues?

Second, if I have a background that is 2048 x 1536 and at a 300 dpi, and compress/optimise this image, would it reduce memory usage/CPU usage? Is there documentation that relates to how best to optimise these kinds of images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several techniques to do that. It depends on how you're going to use the images.

1. If it's a background in movement you can split it in tiles, then you render smaller images.
2. Depends on the format, most of the people just know PNG and JPEG, but there are other projects/formats you can use. Some of them are the smaller size but slower read/write, so is up to you how to use them. **i.e.:** https://github.com/onevcat/APNGKit
3. If in your background is not necessary the alpha channel, use JPEG over PNG then you'll save some space.